# dynamically nest DataTemplates in ListView

Tags: wpf, listview, datatemplate

I have an object of Type MyTypeOneViewModel that is displayed in the first column of ListView and I have an object of Type MyTypeTwoViewModel that is displayed in the 2nd column of my ListView. Both types have a property of type MyNestedViewModel. Now I would like to display a different DataTemplate for each cell in the ListView depending on the actual Type of that Property. For example if the property actually holds a MyDoubleNestedViewModel I want to display a Textbox in that cell and if that property holds a MyBooleanNestedViewModel I want to display a ComboBox in that particular cell of the ListView. Note that The DataTemplate could vary in each row and column.

Can I achieve this without a TemplateSelector? WPF is able to autmatically chose the right DataTemplate based on the bound Type. But does that work in this nested scenario in a ListView too somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider these options:

**1. Bind directly to the sub-property.**

Bind the column to the sub-property (of type `MyNestedViewModel`) rather than the parent. WPF will then pick a template based on the type of the nested view model, rather than the type of the parent view model.

```
<GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TheChildViewModel}"/>
```

**2. Include a `ContentControl` in your cell template.**

In your grid column templates, bind a `ContentControl` to the child property:

```
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="{Binding SomePropertyOnParentViewModel}"/>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding TheChildViewModel}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

WPF can do exactly what you want.

Reference the assembly that has your data types and add a DataTemplate resource for each type you need to display.

```
 xmlns:ui="clr-namespace:YourAssembly"
    <Window.Resources>

        <DataTemplate DataType="ui:MyDoubleNestedViewModel ">
              <Grid Margin="5,5,5,5" >

                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value}"/>                                                     
        </Grid>

        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="ui:MyBooleanNestedViewModel ">
              <Grid Margin="5,5,5,5" >

                   <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}"/>                                                       
        </Grid>

        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
```

Now this template will be used with any list or content control in this window that’s
bound to your view model objects. You don’t need to specify the ItemTemplate setting.